# How to get textbox value from inside html tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, parameterized-query

I want to select data from SqlDataSource tag to gridview using TextBox1 value. how can I modify that ASP.net code behind file.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
SelectCommand= "select distinct [Species],[qty],[received],[Discard],[mortility],[dispatch],[dispatch],[dpt_sales] from  [vw_getFishDtls] where [Tank_id]=TextBox1.Text and [ftype] =(select [ftype] from [vw_getFishType] where [Tank_id]=TextBox1.Text"
ConnectionString="Data Source=IT-ISHAN;Initial Catalog=ETF;User Id=ishanuk77; Password=ishanuk77;">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ControlParameter` as below

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
SelectCommand= "select distinct [Species],[qty],[received],[Discard],[mortility],[dispatch],[dispatch],[dpt_sales] from  [vw_getFishDtls] where [Tank_id]=TextBox1.Text and [ftype] =(select [ftype] from [vw_getFishType] where [Tank_id]=@Tank_id"
ConnectionString="Data Source=IT-ISHAN;Initial Catalog=ETF;User Id=ishanuk77; Password=ishanuk77;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Tank_id"
            PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```